# Extract interface properties from object

Tags: vb.net

Take this code...

```
Public Interface IPersonName
    Property FirstName As String
    Property LastName As String
End Interface

Public Class Person
    Implements IPersonName
    Public Property FirstName As String Implements IPersonName.FirstName
    Public Property LastName As String Implements IPersonName.LastName
    Public Property Age As Integer
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim p As New Person With {
        .Age = 11,
        .FirstName = "John",
        .LastName = "Doe"}

    Dim p2 As IPersonName = p
    ' p2 contains age ???
End Sub
```

I was hoping that the p2 variable only would containt FirstName and LastName, but it also contains Age.

How can I extract IPersonName properties only from the `p` variable? I want to extract only FirstName and LastName.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly have `Option Strict Off`, which is a bad thing.

If you do this:

```vb
Dim p2 As IPersonName = p

Dim f = p2.f
```

what do you see? You see Intellisense suggest the `FirstName` property, right? That's because `FirstName` is a member of the `IPersonName` type. Now, if you do this:

```vb
Dim p2 As IPersonName = p

Dim a = p2.a
```

what do you see? You don't see anything because Intellisense has nothing to suggest that matches. That's because `Age` is not a member of that type. You can type the property name yourself, but the compiler cannot confirm that any such member exists, so it relies on late binding. At run time, the system checks the type of the object and whether that object has a member with that name. If it does, it will be invoked. If it doesn't, you'll see an exception thrown. With `Option Strict Off`, late binding is allowed and you could do this:

```vb
Dim p2 As IPersonName = p

Dim f = p2.FirstName
Dim l = p2.LastName
Dim a = p2.Age
Dim x = p2.SomeMemmberThatDoesNotExist
```

and the compiler will not complain. If you execute that code though, an exception will be thrown on the last line.

What you should do is turn `Option Strict On` and disallow late binding altogether. You should turn it `On` in the project properties and you should turn it `On` in the VS options so that it will be `On` by default for all future projects. You should ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` at the project level and only turn it `Off` at the file level where late binding is explicitly required, which is rare. Even then, you should use partial classes to ensure that the amount of code in such files is an absolute minimum.

If you do that then late binding will be disallowed and this code:

```vb
Dim p2 As IPersonName = p

Dim f = p2.FirstName
Dim l = p2.LastName
Dim a = p2.Age
```

will refuse to compile. The last line will generate a compilation error with the message that `Age` is not a member of the `IPersonName` type.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!! If I turn "Option Strict On" and change the code to .... "Dim p2 As IPersonName = CType(p, IPersonName)" ... then I still get the Age property. I need to extract only the properties that are in the interface (FirstName and LastName).

Comment: @MojoDK, firstly, there's no need or point to casting `p` as type `IPersonName` because it already is that type. Just do a straight assignment. Secondly, you're wrong. Unless your IDE is broken, which I doubt, what you're describing is not happening. Either you haven't turned `Option Strict On` for that code or you've done something else wrong. I've tested the actual code you posted and it behaves exactly as I've described, which I already knew would be the case.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is confused by the fact that debugger shows the 'Age' property on the p2 object (I just tried it), even though you can't use the 'Age' property via the p2 object in actual code. Weird that the debugger does this...

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I don't think it's that weird, the debugger tries to show everything based on the object's runtime type.  I'd much rather it behave that way than to have to jump through a bunch of hoops to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

The properties in the class are set to Public. You need to create a Get/Set pair for them to hide it to other classes.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer